# DNN 8 Search function misbehaving

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have upgraded a site from DNN 7 to DNN 8
http://esiwebsitedev.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/

We encountered problems like pages redirect to 404 pages and search results are misbehaving.

http://esiwebsitedev.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/Search-Results?search=crm

notice the indented search results, the don't return any links

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The indented results are actually results from the Modules on that page. Notice the titles

Results to http://esiwebsitedev.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/advisory

has modules on the page

Advisory Services for Microsoft ERP and CRM

I think you're just seeing results of the way the new Search in DNN8 works